# calling stage.act call in different thread a good idea in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

Will calling `stage.act` on a seperate thread within an infinite loop is a good idea?
Is there any pros and cons on this approach?

I've tried doing it,but im not sure if this will cause problem in the long run. it looks faster though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [LibGDX documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading):

> No class in libgdx is thread-safe unless explicitly marked as thread-safe in the class documentation.
>
> You should never perform multi-threaded operations on anything that is
>   graphics or audio related, e.g. use scene2D components from multiple
>   threads.

From [Stage api](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html):

> The Stage and its constituents (like Actors and Listeners) are not thread-safe and should only be updated and queried from a single thread (presumably the main render thread).

**So how you can see, it's a bad idea.**

Answer (score 0):

We always write stage.act in render method and purpose of that we get time(dt) between 2 render method(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) call. You can write stage.act in your own loop. but for that you have to manage stop calling stage.act().

If you want to set same anim speed in every device then you should use
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()).

Comment: How this answers the question? He knows how to draw and update stage and where to do this. I guess. Read a question before answering.

Comment: I mean your answer is obvious.